# dictionary reconstruction format from old dictionary data

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary below

```
dict1 = {'index': 88260', 'host': 'digital.net', 'source': '11-02.txt', '_time': '2018 9:00 EDT', 'count': '1'}
```

Is it a way to reconstruct to a new dictionary?

```
{
 "name1": {
    "index": "88260",                
    "host": "digitalnet"
 },
 "time": '2018 9:00 EDT',
 "name2": {                    
    "source": '11-02.txt'
 },
 "metricName": "test 1",   
 "count_value": 1,
 "metricType": "count"              
}
```

so far I only can get the name1 part which is

```
d1_items = list(dict1.items())

dic2={"name1":{k: v for k, v in d1_items[0:2]}}
```

What will be the next steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your data correctly, since the new dictionary contains keys that don't exist in the original dictionary, I'm not sure if there's a better way other than manually building a new dictionary for each key-value pair.

If I misunderstood something please comment, otherwise...

The only thing I really added was sorting the `d1_items` list since dictionaries are unordered by design, so the only way to ensure we get the correct key-value pair is to first sort the data:

```
dict1 = {'index': '88260', 
         'host': 'digital.net', 
         'source': '11-02.txt', 
         '_time': '2018 9:00 EDT', 
         'count': '1'}

new_keys = ['name1', 'time', 'name2', 'metricName', 'count_value', 'metricType']

d1_items = sorted(dict1.items())

d2 = {}

d2[new_keys[0]] = {k:v for k, v in d1_items[2:4]}
d2[new_keys[1]] = d1_items[0][1]
d2[new_keys[2]] = {d1_items[4][0]: d1_items[4][1]}
d2[new_keys[3]] = 'test 1'
d2[new_keys[4]] = int(d1_items[1][1])
d2[new_keys[5]] = d1_items[1][0]
```

the new dictionary, `d2`, is created, now let's take a look at it:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(d2)

{'count_value': 1,
 'metricName': 'test 1',
 'metricType': 'count',
 'name1': {'host': 'digital.net', 'index': '88260'},
 'name2': {'source': '11-02.txt'},
 'time': '2018 9:00 EDT'}
```

Looks promising, let's check that it matches our desired dictionary result.

```
desired = {
    "name1": {
    "index": "88260",                
    "host": "digital.net"
    },
    "time": '2018 9:00 EDT',
    "name2": {                    
    "source": '11-02.txt'
    },
    "metricName": "test 1",   
    "count_value": 1,
    "metricType": "count"              
}

def compare(a, b):
    return (a > b) - (a < b) 

print(compare(d2, desired)) # 0 mean they are Equal
```

Comment: Hi Dave, you are right, I created one manually. and you are right the sorted is really useful.